# Preview docx file in Vue

Tags: vue.js, docx

Is there any way to preview docx file in vue.js?

Docx file is uploaded by the `input` tag with `type="file"`.

I have tried to use [vue-doc-preview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-doc-preview) npm, but it needs the url of the online url, not the local url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found the solution by using [pdftron](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/vue/).

1. Install `@pdftron/webviewer`.

```
npm install --save @pdftron/webviewer
```

2. Add script to package.json.

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "postinstall": "node ./init-webviewer.js"
   ...
}
```

3. create `init-webviewer.js` in the root of the project.

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const copyFiles = async () => {
  try {
    await fs.copy('./node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public', './public/webviewer/');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

copyFiles();
```

4. In vue file, use WebViewer.

```
...
    <div ref='viewer'"></div>
...

import WebViewer from '@pdftron/webviewer';

    ...

    WebViewer({
      path: `${process.env.BASE_URL}webviewer`,
      fullAPI: true
    }, this.$refs.viewer)
      .then((instance) => {
        instance.loadDocument(this.file); // this.file is the File object to be uploaded.
      });
```